# recognize overall factor in a variable

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression (not necessarily a polynomial) which I know is proportional to an overall power of a symbolic constant, so something like $x^a (...)$. What is the best way to get $a$?

Comment: `Cases[expr, x^a_ :> a, Infinity]`? `FactorList[expr]`?  Hard to say without complete examples....

Comment: I am really asking how to factor out a single variable out of a possibly huge and multivariate expression...

Comment: Unless the `x^a` is a factor of each term it will not factor out. Perhaps you want [`Asymptotic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic.html)

Comment: I know it factors out in the end, so I'd like the most economic way to make it happen.

Comment: If you don't want $a$ per se but only to factor, use `Factor[expr]`. Or maybe `FactorTerms[3 x^a y + 6 x^(a + 1) + 3 x^(a + 2) y z, {y, z}]`

Comment: I guess that would work, thanks. Only one minor thing, like that I have to know what are all the other symbols appearing in the expression other than x. Is there a way to just enforce the factorization by stating what is the variable which is to be factored out (rather than the opposite)?

Comment: I guess I really want mathematica to keep applying the distributive property to replace x^a (...) + x^a(...) + -> x^a (...) as long as it can be done

Comment: Apparently not. I supposed that's because the function would have to scan the expression for all symbols, which would be slightly time-consuming; in most cases, the user already knows what they are. If you have a list of all variables, you could call it thus: `FactorTerms[expr, DeleteCases[allvars, x]]`